# Can we show a popup when android app is closed?

Tags: android, popup

is it possible to show the popup when the app is closed? It will have an action button to launch the app again.

Comment: You can show a notification instead but beware such actions are generally looked down by end users leading to negative reviews and feedbacks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant. You can use PopUp only inside your app.
But you may use **Widgets** and **Notifications** instead of PopUp.